# How change "Vary color by point" setting in PowerPoint chart?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, ms-office, powerpoint

By default, an MS Office bar chart having a single series appears with each bar in a different color.

In the *Format Data Series* dialog, there is an option named "Vary color by point" on the *Fill* panel that allows this to be changed. This checkbox only appears when there is a single series, and unchecking it causes all the bars to be shown in the *Accent 1* color.

I'll be darned if I can figure out how to do that via the API using VBA or C#. Do you know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recording a Macro in Excel confirms that the property you need is `VaryByCategories`.

```
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
ActiveChart.ChartGroups(1).VaryByCategories = True
Range("D8").Select
```

It is the same property from PowerPoint.

Comment: Cool, thanks, I was missing the idea of ChartGroups and hadn't looked there. From the name I thought it was a group of charts, but in fact it's more like a group of series, a sub-chart so to speak. Most charts have only one chart group, but that's where a lot of the action is from an API perspective :)